# Функция, генерирующая url из массива

Tags: php

Напомните `php`-функцию, генерирующую строку с параметрами для `url` по переданному массиву.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [http-build-query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php):

```
    $array = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2);

    echo http_build_query($array);
```